# Unity: Responding to the server send with an event handler and then changing the text in the scene but without success

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, signalr

Use signalr to communicate with the server.
This is the code in the client about accepting the server's response.

```
public delegate  void RefreshRoom();
public static event RefreshRoom Refresh;     //Event

public async Task InitAsync()
{
    await StartConnectionAsync();
    connection.On<string>(
        "ReceiveMessage",
        (message) =>
        {
            returnMessage = message;
            isReceive = true;
        }
    );

    connection.On<string>(
        "Check",
        (message) =>
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(message);
                Refresh();                          //Event broadcast       
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Here is the code for subscribing to the event related class.
class1:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    SignalRConnector.Refresh += RefreshRoomPlayerName;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    SignalRConnector.Refresh -= RefreshRoomPlayerName;
}

public void RefreshRoomPlayerName()   //EventHandler
{
    try{
    if (JoinRoomName.Length > 0)
    {
        RefreshName();
    }
    }
    catch{
    }
}
```

class2:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    SignalRConnector.Refresh += RefreshHandler;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    SignalRConnector.Refresh -= RefreshHandler;
}

 private void RefreshHandler()   //EventHandler
{
    Debug.Log("123");
    try{
    Player_Enemy.text = "123";   //TMP TextUI
    }
    catch{
        Debug.Log("456");
    }
}
```

Situation description:
I want the server to change the text accordingly.
The first time the response occurs when switching scenes, debug only shows server information.
The second time in response to other users entering the server group, debug shows the server information, "123" and "456", and the text in the Inspector has changed to "123", but the text in the scene has not changed.
The third time it responds when other users leave the server group, debug shows server information, and "123".
After each server response, debug will only display server information and "123". And the text in the scene never changes.

I have absolutely no idea why the event handler is not properly implemented in the second class. Obviously everything works fine in the first class.

I guess based on debug that it may be because of the life cycle. But I can't find a solution.

Thanks.